# Path finding algorithm for (x,y) coordinates in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding

I am trying to code a path finding function in c++ . It should work like that, you supply the start point (x1,y1) and the end point(x2,y2) and it returns a list of points for the shortest path.

[image: image for illustration]

Assume that i want to go from the red tile to the blue one, however the grey tiles can not be walked on (like walls) .

Comment: And what are you having trouble with? What path-finding algorithm to use? Or an issue with your existing code?

Comment: what algorithm should i use?

Comment: Then it seems that your question has already been answered (multiple times) already. Check out the link I posted above.